# Angular Materials won't apply styles to components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

Here is a simple snippet:

```css
.profilebutton  {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- PROFILE BUTTON -->
  <div class="col-md-4 profilebuttoncontainer">
    <button md-button [routerLink]="'/welcome/profile'" class="profilebutton">Profile</button>
  </div>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I have been trying to style toolbars, dialog boxes, checkboxes all from Angular Materials but none of them apply. I can change the styling with the inspector under mat-(whatever) like mat-button, mat-dialog-container, and that works, but how do I translate that to css? It seems I don't have access to modifying the mat-(stuff)

All I want to do is stick an md-button to the right side of a container. Super simple.

Comment: @Vega It's obviously Angular since the material button has a `md-button` attribute and not as an element.

Comment: can you upvote this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as expected. See the below code,

```
<div class="profilebuttoncontainer">
     <button md-button class="temp-class">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Note : Add the stylesheet reference at the component level using below line

```
styleUrls:[`....`]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sV6QC0VKRGEFlwJ1296F?p=preview)**