# Target specific element style by Id or Class inside angular material 2 element using CSS

Tags: angular, css, angular-material2

I am having an EntryComponent that has a material button menu. 
When I try to override the default style by using ::ng-deep the styling changes for all the button component in the parent Component as well.

```
 <style>
 ::ng-deep .mat-button{
  max-width: 50px !important;
  min-width: 45px !important;
  height: 5em;
 }
 ::ng-deep .mat-button-ripple mat-ripple{
  max-width: 40px !important;
  min-width: 20px !important;
 }
 </style>
```

I also tried to target styling using a class but it doesn't work like usual CSS I guess.

```
 <style>
 .actions ::ng-deep .mat-button{
  max-width: 50px !important;
  min-width: 45px !important;
  height: 5em;
 }

 .actions ::ng-deep .mat-button-ripple mat-ripple{
  max-width: 40px !important;
  min-width: 20px !important;
 }
 </style>
```

Please share your experience or knowledge.

Entry Component

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="actions">
<md-icon>flash_on</md-icon></button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">

  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>autorenew</md-icon>
  </button>

  <button md-menu-item>
   <md-icon>border_color</md-icon>
  </button>

  <button md-menu-item>
   <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
  </button>

  <button md-menu-item>
   <md-icon>perm_identity</md-icon>
  </button>

  <button md-menu-item>
   <md-icon>payment</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

PS: this is not a duplicate issue as mentioned as we are able to style material elements globally but the question was how to style a targeted dom element by means of Id or Class. Hope this clears the confusion

Comment: you should use /deep/

Comment: Thanks it worked, bummer I wrote the syntax incorrectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Materials won't apply styles to components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765024/angular-materials-wont-apply-styles-to-components)

Comment: @Aravind Sorry but this is not the same case, my concern was that if I override the material CSS in the entry component, then the effect takes place globally for all material element in the current view. 

I wished to target a specific element either by ID or Class attribute through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by Milad just needed to use this styling

```
<style>
:host /deep/ .actions{
  max-width: 50px !important;
  min-width: 45px !important;
  height: 5em;
}

:host /deep/ .actions .mat-button-ripple mat-ripple{
  max-width: 40px !important;
  min-width: 20px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It is still suggested that you use `::ng-deep`, as it is interchangeable with `/deep/` and [will have longer support](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). You were simply missing the `:host` selector.

Comment: @WillHowell could you elaborate, as in the syntax for the above

    ::ng-deep :host .actions .mat-button-ripple mat-ripple{}

Comment: You probably want `:host ::ng-deep .actions .mat-button-ripple mat-ripple`. The `:host` selector will select your view encapsulated component. You also do **not** need to use `::ng-deep` for the styling of `.actions` since it is a direct child of your EntryComponent