# Angular Material 2 target elements in CSS

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material to make the UI more "google-style" although, I want to manipulate the default CSS at some points. For example, this is my markup/angular-material code:

```
   <mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Experience">
        <div *ngFor="let item of experienceItems"> 
          <mat-card>
             <mat-card-header>
             <mat-card-title> {{item?.startDate}} - {{item?.endDate}} <span class="card-company">{{item?.company}} - {{item?.location}}</span></mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-subtitle>{{item?.jobTitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
              <i class="fa fa-keyboard-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{item?.description}}
            </mat-card-content> 
          </mat-card> 
          <br/>
       </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I want to replace some default values from the label like:

```
.mat-tab-label{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    /*remove min-width*/
}
```

but it doesn't work..

**My CSS is located like:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './template/app-about.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css/style.css']
})
```

Any CSS applying to other elements, works pretty good. For Angular Material elements, it doesn't.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: you can refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765024/angular-materials-wont-apply-styles-to-components/45766092#45766092)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For angular material you'll need to use `::ng-deep`.

In your css do:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
 text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    /*remove min-width*/
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please choose my answer as best and let's call it a day :)

Comment: 8 more minutes..!